# Regex expression for 2 identical strings in a row

Tags: regex

So I am trying to create a regex expression for the following template.

```
"[alphaNumeric]String/String.xcl"
```

So

- `[a1B2c3]Hello/Hello.xcl` would pass
- `a1B2c3]hello/hello.xcl` fails
- `[a1B2c3]Hello/hello.xcl` fails
- `[a1B2c3]hello/hello.xc` fails

I have tried the following so far:

```
\[[\da-zA-Z]+\][a-z]+\/[a-z]+\.xcl$
```

How do I check if the middle strings are identical?

Comment: Wasn't my answer was correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a backreference:

```
\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]([^/]+)/\1\.xcl
```

The term in parenthesis captures the first part of your path.  We may then refer to it later in the regex using `\1`.

Depending on how you plan to use this regex, you might need optional starting and closing anchors (`^` and `$`).

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You may [**capture**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the part after brackets and use a [**backreference**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) after `/`:

```
^\[[\da-zA-Z]+]([A-Za-z]+)\/\1\.xcl$
               ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yttbPA/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `\[` - a `[`
- `[\da-zA-Z]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `]` - a `]` char
- `([A-Za-z]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more letters
- `\/` - a slash
- `\1` - a backreference to capturing group 1 value
- `\.xcl` - `.xcl` substring
- `$` - end of string.

NOTE: If you do not care about what kind of chars there can be inside brackets, you may replace `[\da-zA-Z]+`  with `[^\]]+`.

NOTE2: If you want to match any chars on both ends of `/`, replace `([A-Za-z]+)` with `([^\/]+)`.